Integrating ODEs: "No gradients provided for any variable"
I am trying to solve a Neural ODE. The issue I am having is that the tape is not taping. I tried debugging with ChatGPT with no avail. Basically what I am trying to do here is to make a copy of an already known ODE system. I am new in Python and I struggle trying to understand the already written packages. The error I get is "No gradients provided for any variable" in line optm.apply_gradients(zip(grad_w, NN.trainable_variables)).  For some reason the gradient cannot be recorded inside odeint. Help is much appreciated.
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras

# Define true model
A = np.array([[-0.1, -1], [1, -0.1]])
x0 = np.array([2, 0])

def true_model(x0, t):
    xdot = np.dot(A, x0)
    return xdot

# Generate training data
num_time_steps = 2000
T = 15
t = np.linspace(0, T, num_time_steps)
x_train = odeint(true_model, x0, t)

optm = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001)

NN = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input((2,)),  # Change input shape to (2,)
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=32, activation='tanh'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2)
])

def NN_model(x, t):
    # Reshape input tensor if needed
    x = tf.reshape(x, (1, -1)) if len(x.shape) == 1 else x
    # Pass the input tensor through the model
    xdot = NN(x)[0]
    return xdot

# # Convert t_tensor to a TensorFlow constant
t_tensor  = tf.constant(t, dtype=tf.float32)
x_tensor  = tf.constant(x_train, dtype=tf.float32)
x0_tensor = tf.constant(x0, dtype=tf.float32)

for itr in range(1):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        x_calculated = odeint(NN_model, x0_tensor, t_tensor)
        ode_loss     = x_calculated - x_train
        square_loss  = tf.square(ode_loss)
        total_loss   = tf.reduce_mean(square_loss)
        
        grad_w = tape.gradient(total_loss, NN.trainable_variables)
        optm.apply_gradients(zip(grad_w, NN.trainable_variables))
        print(grad_w)
        print(total_loss)

I expect to be able to train the neural network to estimate the state variable derivatives and use an integrator to obtain the state variables which are then compared to the dataset.
